# force chef to reload packages list/versions

Tags: chef-infra

OS: debian 7. It has nginx 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy4 preinstalled.

I'm writing a cookbook that should upgrade nginx to latest version:

```
# Remove old versions if found
['nginx', 'nginx-common', 'nginx-full'].each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    version '1.2.1-2.2+wheezy4'
    action :nothing
  end.run_action(:remove)
end

# Install nginx repository
include_recipe 'chef_nginx::repo'

# Forces nginx installations from nginx repo
apt_preference 'dotdeb' do
  glob 'nginx*'
  pin 'release o=nginx'
  pin_priority '1000'
end

# This should install latest nginx ! But it installs 1.2.1!
package 'nginx'
```

why chef installs old version of nginx? :( How to force it to reload packages version.

```
# apt-cache policy
...
Pinned packages:
...
nginx -> 1.10.3-1~wheezy
```

Comment: Specify the version you want in the last `package 'nginx'` resource, like you did in the first one.
Also, try logging into the machine and check what does `apt-get install nginx` try to install, maybe your repo is wrong.

Comment: I don't want to use hard-coded version. Regarding manual apt-get.. it works fine.. see 'apt-cache policy' above

Comment: You don't have to hardcode it in the recipe, use an attribute so it can be changed on a role/environment/policy basis.

Comment: yep. thanks. this is workaround...the basic question is how to force chef to update package versions (that he has in memory).... I tried ohai reload - this don't help :(

Comment: See https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_update.html that's not a chef problem, it's apt not aware the repo list has changed. The nginx cookbook should do that while adding the repo...

Answer (score 0):

Chef does not track apt/deb versions in memory so the issue is with apt itself. You might have read some confusing guides elsewhere since we do have some internal caching for yum, but that is only for yum installs.